# android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" change the layout (seems scrolled)

Tags: android, focus, accessibility, android-elevation

I have changed my layout from:

```
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to

```
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

as follows:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

to this:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

and it seems the layout has changed.

*The shadow is bolder and it seems the elevation is higher

*the width became wider

[image]

Why has this happened?

What's the proper way to fix this? elevation, l
How can i be accurate?